# Cuda Matrix Multiplication -- not working for some non-square matrices

Tags: matrix, cuda, gpu, multiplication

I am experimenting with Cuda programming a the moment. As part of this I am attempting to develop a matrix multiplication algorithm to run on GPU. This algorithm works for square matrices but fails for *non-square* matrices.
Here is my kernel

```
    float* multiply_gpu(float* matrix1 , float* matrix2);
    __global__ void mult(int rowsA , int columnsA, int rowsB,int columnsB, float *a,
            float *b, float *result) {
        int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int result_size = rowsA*columnsB;
        int value = 0;//the final result
        //indices of values from input matrices
        if (index < result_size) {
            int index1 = (index/rowsA)*rowsA; //get nearest row
            int index2 = index%columnsB; //get start column
            int k = 0;
            while (k<columnsA) { //columnsA == rowsB
               value += a[index1]*b[index2]; //v = sum a_ik * b_kj
               index1 ++;
               index2 += columnsB;
               k++;
            }
            result[index] = value;
        }
    }
```

After doing a brief sanity check with my supervisor, he has not seen any issues with it.
I believe the problem lies in this function:

```
float* multiply_gpu(float* matrix1 , float* matrix2) {
    //the dimensions of the matrices
    size_t available, total;
    cudaError_t error;
    cudaError err = cudaMemGetInfo(&available, &total);
    if(err != cudaSuccess){
        printf("There was an error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }
    int height1 = matrix1[0];
    int width1 = matrix1[1];
    int height2 = matrix2[0];
    int width2 = matrix2[1];
    if (width1!=height2) {
        return NULL;
    }
    //this array contains the result of the operation
    float* result = (float *) malloc(height1*width2*sizeof(float));
    //pointers for device matrices
    float *d_matrix1;
    float *d_matrix2;
    float *d_result;
    //allocate memory for matrices
    error = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrix1,(size_t)height1*width1*sizeof(float));
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    error = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrix2,height2*width2*sizeof(float));
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    error = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result,height1*width2*sizeof(float));
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //now copy matrices onto device -- note the offset of 2
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_matrix1 , matrix1+2 , height1*width1*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_matrix2 , matrix2+2 , height2*width2*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //launch multiplication kernel
//note I have tried adjusting the kernel values between <<< , >>> to no avail
    mult<<<height1,width2>>>(height1,width1,height2,width2,d_matrix1,d_matrix2,d_result); 
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",height1,width1,height2,width2);
    //make the host block until mult is finished running
    //printf("finished multiplying\n");
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //copy result back
    error = cudaMemcpy(result,d_result,height1*width2*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //free now unneeded cuda memory
    cudaFree(d_matrix1);
    cudaFree(d_matrix2);
    cudaFree(d_result);
    printf("GOT RESULT\n");
    for (int i=0;i<height1*width2;i++) {
        printf("%f ",result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //result ready to be returned
    return result;
}
```

Note that the matrices which are parameters to multiply_gpu have their height at index 0 and width at index 1. The result matrix does not have this information.

An example of incorrect computation:
when I feed the following arrays into multiply_gpu -- {2,3,**1,2,3,4,5,6**} , {3,2,**1,2,3,4,5,6**} the answer should be {22,28,49,64} but instead my unit tests generate {22,28,40,52}. So close! Note that for the dot product of (1,2,3)*(1,2,3) (which is not square) the algorithm is happy... What could be the error here? Thanks for any assistance. Will post a solution if I find one independently.

Comment: There's quite a few questions on the CUDA tag about matrix multiplication.  Have you looked at any?  What happens if you run your code with `cuda-memcheck` ?  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  Voting to close.  You haven't provided a SSCCE.org code.

Comment: Yes matrix multiplication is common on GPU, and there are many SO questions about it. I have read through them but possibly not thoroughly enough. I was just at my wits end and came here to get a sanity check.  Thank you for that link to SSCCE.org -- I am reviewing it now. I am also learning cuda-memcheck. Overall this bug I am facing is consuming me. I think a little more attention to my own code and a review of other matrix multipliers is needed.

Comment: I updated my answer since I still had it not quite right.  I think it is correct now - it works for the case you mention plus three others I tried.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
        int index1 = (index/rowsA)*rowsA; //get nearest row
```

It should be something like this:

```
        int index1 = (index/columnsB)*columnsA; //get nearest row
```

Why is this formulation correct?  The `index1` is used to index through the row elements in `A` that correspond to the row indicated by the output matrix position we are computing.  The output matrix position is just the thread index.  If we (integer) divide the thread index by the number of *columns* in the *output* matrix i.e. `C`, we get the row number in question.  Then, to find the first element of that row in `A`, we multiply by the number of columns in `A`.   This correctly indexes us to the first element of the relevant row in `A`.

Here's a complete app along with my test cases - the only change I made to your code was the change indicated above.

```
$ cat t290.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void mult(int rowsA , int columnsA, int rowsB,int columnsB, float *a, float *b, float *result) {
        int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int result_size = rowsA*columnsB;
        int value = 0;//the final result
        //indices of values from input matrices
        if (index < result_size) {
            int index1 = (index/columnsB)*columnsA; //get nearest row
            int index2 = index%columnsB; //get start column
            int k = 0;
            while (k<columnsA) { //columnsA == rowsB
               value += a[index1]*b[index2]; //v = sum a_ik * b_kj
               index1 ++;
               index2 += columnsB;
               k++;
            }
            result[index] = value;
        }
    }

float* multiply_gpu(float* matrix1 , float* matrix2) {
    //the dimensions of the matrices
    size_t available, total;
    cudaError_t error;
    cudaError err = cudaMemGetInfo(&available, &total);
    if(err != cudaSuccess){
        printf("There was an error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }
    int height1 = matrix1[0];
    int width1 = matrix1[1];
    int height2 = matrix2[0];
    int width2 = matrix2[1];
    if (width1!=height2) {
        printf("fail!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    //this array contains the result of the operation
    float* result = (float *) malloc(height1*width2*sizeof(float));
    //pointers for device matrices
    float *d_matrix1;
    float *d_matrix2;
    float *d_result;
    //allocate memory for matrices
    error = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrix1,(size_t)height1*width1*sizeof(float));
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    error = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrix2,height2*width2*sizeof(float));
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    error = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result,height1*width2*sizeof(float));
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //now copy matrices onto device -- note the offset of 2
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_matrix1 , matrix1+2 , height1*width1*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_matrix2 , matrix2+2 , height2*width2*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //launch multiplication kernel
//note I have tried adjusting the kernel values between <<< , >>> to no avail
    mult<<<height1,width2>>>(height1,width1,height2,width2,d_matrix1,d_matrix2,d_result);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",height1,width1,height2,width2);
    error = cudaGetLastError();
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //make the host block until mult is finished running
    //printf("finished multiplying\n");
    error = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "kernel fail (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //copy result back
    error = cudaMemcpy(result,d_result,height1*width2*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy memory (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //free now unneeded cuda memory
    cudaFree(d_matrix1);
    cudaFree(d_matrix2);
    cudaFree(d_result);
    printf("GOT RESULT\n");
    for (int i=0;i<height1*width2;i++) {
        printf("%f ",result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //result ready to be returned
    return result;
}

int main(){

  float m1[8] = {2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
  float m2[6] = {2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0};
  float *my_result1 = multiply_gpu(m2, m1);
  float m3[8] = {2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6};
  float m4[8] = {3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6};
  float *my_result2 = multiply_gpu(m3, m4);
  float *my_result3 = multiply_gpu(m4, m3);
  float m5[12] = {2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
  float m6[22] = {5,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
  float *my_result4 = multiply_gpu(m5, m6);
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t290 t290.cu
t290.cu: In function âfloat* multiply_gpu(float*, float*)â:
t290.cu:30: warning: converting to âintâ from âfloatâ
t290.cu:31: warning: converting to âintâ from âfloatâ
t290.cu:32: warning: converting to âintâ from âfloatâ
t290.cu:33: warning: converting to âintâ from âfloatâ
$ cuda-memcheck ./t290
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
2 2 2 3
GOT RESULT
5.000000 7.000000 9.000000 10.000000 14.000000 18.000000
2 3 3 2
GOT RESULT
22.000000 28.000000 49.000000 64.000000
3 2 2 3
GOT RESULT
9.000000 12.000000 15.000000 19.000000 26.000000 33.000000 29.000000 40.000000 51.000000
2 5 5 4
GOT RESULT
5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 5.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Hmmm not quite. But you are on the right track. I have discovered the correct answer myself and am posting it.

Answer (score 0):

So after carefully reviewing my matrix code I discovered a simple problem with
the mathematics of my operation.

It is true this line was wrong

```
 int index1 = (index/rowsA)*rowsA; //get nearest row
```

I note that since my matrix is row-ordered, the formula for acquiring the correct index from element at (i,j) is

```
index = i*rowLength + j
```

Therefore the assignment to index1 should be

```
int index1 = (index/rowsA)*columnsA
```

Why? Well it's obvious that to navigate to the index for row *n*, we have to move by *n* row lengths (this is the number of columns in the matrix). My code worked for square matrices but not other rectangular ones because the number of columns doesn't match the number of rows in such a matrix.

Comment: This is wrong. I've provided a complete code.  Plug your formulation into my complete code, it gives incorrect results.